# Remove both the square brackets and their contents, as well as any occurrence of a comma or hyphen that follows the closed bracket in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking for a regex to use in Notepad++ for deleting all square brackets and their contents, as well as any occurrence of a comma or hyphen that follows the closed bracket. The regex should detect the following examples inside the text for removal:

```
[1]–[5]
[Alibaba], [7], [8]
[1-2]–[5]
```

I don't care about the spaces after comma and they can stay.

So far I could catch the brackets and their content by `\[[^\]]*\]`.

Comment: What about the space following a comma?

Comment: @PoulBak I don't care about the space after comma.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes the space can stay. Not necessarily, I have another case `[17-325]`

Comment: Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76451169/edit) your question with that information (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** ****** *** *** ****** *** *** ****** *** *** ****** *** *** ****** *** *** ****** *** *** ****** *** *** ****** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your regex this way to capture following comma and hyphen:`\[[^\]]*\](?:,|-)?`